# When using two "weareoutman ClockPicker", why the second one does not function in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have used [weareoutman ClockPicker](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) in my MVC project and it is perfectly working when I have only one clockPicker field in my View. When for example for Meeting table I need a *start* and an *end* time, the second clockPicker does not function(when I click there is no clockPicker).

Here's how I use it in my Create View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StringStartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StringStartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control clockPicker", id = "single-input", value = "", placeholder = "اکنون" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StringStartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StringEndTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StringEndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control clockPicker", id = "single-input", value = "", placeholder = "اکنون" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StringEndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

So again the problem: the second clockPicker does not function(After clicking on the text box, the clockpicker does not pop up). What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is there anybody out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by giving the *EndTime* a different *id*.